# Build signed apk error with duplicate zip entry message when integrated Giphy SDK as module

Tags: android, android-proguard

I'm trying to integrate Giphy SDK into the current project. I've followed the instructions from https://github.com/Giphy/giphy-android-sdk-core and it works like a charm.
But it fails to generate signed apk with the following message:

```
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/xxxxx/Documents/myApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/facebook/release/jars/3/1f/main.jar] (Can't read [/Users/xxxxx/Documents/myApp/app/build/intermediates/transforms/FirebasePerformancePlugin/facebook/release/folders/1/4/9295f6fdf93ed7497ff128b73dc55529-classes(;;;;;;**.class)] (Can't read [com] (Can't read [giphy] (Can't read [sdk] (Can't read [core] (Can't read [network] (Can't read [response] (Can't read [ListMediaResponse.class] (Duplicate zip entry [com/giphy/sdk/core/network/response/ListMediaResponse.class])))))))))
```

I've added the pro-guard rules but didn't work out.

```
-keep public class com.giphy.sdk.core.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.giphy.sdk.core.**
```

Any way to resolve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore it in the right place! Here: build.gradle

android {
    // defaultConfig, buildTypes, etc.

```
lintOptions {
    disable 'MissingTranslation'
}
```

}

Comment: lintOptions {
            disable "ResourceType"

        }

Answer (score 0):

Found myself misplaced the package including,

```
compile('com.giphy.sdk:core:1.0.0@aar') {
    transitive=true
}
```

This should be added after you import it as a module and need to put this in the build.gradle file "in the module", instead of the one in your project. Though this has been mentioned on the github page and I've read it, didn't expect it goes wrong just because of this. Besides, why didn't they just put it? lol.